# Is it safe to send a pointer to a static function over the network?

Tags: c++, c, function-pointers

I was thinking about some RPC code that I have to implement in C++ and I wondered if it's safe (and under which assumptions) to send it over the network to the same binary code (assuming it's exactly the same and that they are running on same architecture). I guess virtual memory should do the difference here.

I'm asking it just out of curiosity, since it's a bad design in any case, but I would like to know if it's theoretically possible (and if it's extendable to other kind of pointers to static data other than functions that the program may include).

Comment: Regardless of good or bad idea, it won't work. Even without [ASLR](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Address_space_layout_randomization), you would have to be very lucky to always have the pointer be the same address consistently. With ASLR, you are pretty much guaranteed it never will be.

Comment: No. Nothing over the network without encryption is safe. Calling functions without some sort of promise it will work (because the pointer *will* move on you) isn't safe either. Use a protocol.

Comment: Don't worry, I'm not going to do that, I'm just wondering about if it's possible and under which circumstances.

Comment: Couldn't you send a symbol that you translate to a pointer on both ends?

Comment: @Darren Kopp: On a typical modern virtual flat-memory system *without* ASLR a pointer to an ordinary function will pretty much always be the same in all processes started from the same executable (even on different machines). The whole idea is of course rather ugly, but it *will* work, no luck required. Actually the whole reason behind the introduction of ASLR and similar techniques is the simple fact that it *works* and works very reliably. The purpose of ASLR is to suppress that unwanted parasitic "reliability".

Comment: ASLR is only a problem if the module where the functions are located is moved. Which for 32 bit processes under Windows is not the case, unless the PE image provides the necessary relocation information (which most EXEs don't) and explicitly requests to be moved (which almost no non-system EXE does). Just moving around other modules (like system DLLs) will not cause any troubles.

Comment: @PaulGroke: You've got it precisely the wrong way around. If there's no explicit request to be moved (which is indeed the default), the load address is entirely dependent on DLLs loaded previously and therefore far less predictable. A "rebased" DLL will have a preferred location, usually get that and therefore have its functions at predictable locations.

Comment: @MSalters: I was talking about ASLR, and ASLR only forces a move if it's requested. What you are talking about is the preferred load address. Which every DLL has, only if you don't specify an address yourself (`/BASE`) the linker will choose a fixed default (0x10000000 for DLLs). Which results in many DLLs having exactly that preferred load address, which means chances are high that it isn't free. The rebase.exe utility that you're referring to only *changes* the preferred load address. But again, all that has nothing to do with ASLR.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In general, it's not safe for many reasons, but there are limited cases in which it will work. First of all, I'm going to assume you're using some sort of signing or encryption in the protocol that ensures the integrity of your data stream; if not, you have serious security issues *already* that are only compounded by passing around function pointers.

If the exact same program binary is running on both ends of the connection, if the function is in the main program (or in code linked from a static library) and not in a shared library, and if the program is not built as a position-independent executable (PIE), then the function pointer will be the same on both ends and passing it across the network should work. Note that these are very stringent conditions that would have to be documented as part of using your program, and they're very fragile; for instance if somebody upgrades the software on one side and forgets to upgrade the version on the other side of the connection at the same time, things will break horribly and dangerously.

I would avoid this type of low-level RPC entirely in favor of a higher-level command structure or abstract RPC framework, but if you really want to do it, a slightly safer approach would be to pass function names and use `dlsym` or equivalent to look them up. If the symbols reside in the main program binary rather than libraries, then depending on your platform you might need `-rdynamic` (GCC) or a similar option to make them available to `dlsym`. `libffi` might also be a useful tool for abstracting this.

Also, if you want to avoid depending on `dlsym` or `libffi`, you could keep your own "symbol table" hard-coded in the binary as a `static const` linear table or hash table mapping symbol names to function pointers. The hash table format used in ELF for this purpose is very simple to understand and implement, so I might consider basing your implementation on that.

Answer (score 1):

What is it a pointer to?

Is it a pointer to a piece of static program memory? If so, don't forget that it's an address, not an offset, so you'd first need to convert between the two accordingly.

Second, if it's not a piece of static memory (ie: statically allocated array created at build time as opposed to run time) it's not really possible at all.

Finally, how are you ensuring the two pieces of code are the same? Are both binaries bit identical (eg: `diff -a binary1 binary2`). Even if they are bit-identical, depending on the virtual memory management on each machine, the entire program's program memory segment may not exist in a single page, or the alignment across multiple pages may be different for each system.

This is really a bad idea, no matter how you slice it. This is what message passing and APIs are for.

Answer (score 1):

This is highly system dependent.  On systems with virtual addressing such that each process thinks it's running at the same address each time it executes, this could plausibly work for executable code.  Darren Kopp's comment and link regarding ASLR is interesting - a quick read of the Wikipedia article suggests the Linux & Windows versions focus on data rather than executable code, except for "network facing daemons" on Linux, and on Windows it applies only when "specifically linked to be ASLR-enabled".

Still, "same binary code" is best assured by static linking - if different shared objects/libraries are loaded, or they're loaded in different order (perhaps due to dynamic loading - `dlopen` - driven by different ordering in config files or command line args etc.) you're probably stuffed.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know of any form of RPC that will let you send a pointer over the network (at least without doing something like casting to `int` first). If you do convert to `int` on the sending end, and convert that back to a pointer on the far end, you get pretty much the same as converting any other arbitrary `int` to a pointer: undefined behavior if you ever attempt to dereference it.

Normally, if you pass a pointer to an RPC function, it'll be marshalled -- i.e., the data it points to will be packaged up, sent across, put into memory, and a pointer to that local copy of the data passed to the function on the other end. That's part of why/how IDL gets a bit ugly -- you need to tell it how to figure out how much data to send across the wire when/if you pass a pointer. Most know about zero-terminated strings. For other types of arrays, you typically need to specify the size of the data (somehow or other).

Answer (score 1):

Sending a pointer over the network is generally unsafe. The two main reasons are:

- **Reliability**: the data/function pointer may not point to the same entity (data structure or function) on another machine due to different location of the program or its libraries or dynamically allocated objects in memory. Relocatable code + ASLR can break your design. At the very least, if you want to point to a statically allocated object or a function you should sent its offset w.r.t. the image base if your platform is Windows or do something similar on whatever OS you are.
- **Security**: if your network is open and there's a hacker (or they have broken into your network), they can impersonate your first machine and make the second machine either hang or crash, causing a denial of service, or execute arbitrary code and get access to sensitive information or tamper with it or hijack the machine and turn it into an evil bot sending spam or attacking other computers. Of course, there are measures and countermeasures here, but...

If I were you, I'd design something different. And I'd ensure that the transmitted data is either unimportant or encrypted and the receiving part does the necessary validation of it prior to using it, so there are no buffer overflows or execution of arbitrary things.

Answer (score 1):

If you're looking for some formal guarantees, I cannot help you. You would have to look in the documentation of the compiler and OS that you're using - however I doubt that you would find the necessary guarantees - except possibly for some specialized embedded systems OS'.

I can however provide you with one scenario where I'm 99.99% sure that it will work without any problems:

- Windows
- 32 bit process
- Function is located in a module that doesn't have relocation information
- The module in question is already loaded & initialized on the client side
- The module in question is 100% identical on both sides
- A compiler that doesn't do very crazy stuff (e.g. MSVC and GCC should both be fine)

If you want to call a function in a DLL you might run into problems. As per the list above the module (=DLL) may not have relocation information, which of course makes it impossible to relocate it (which is what we need). Unfortunately that also means that loading the DLL will fail, if the "preferred load address" is used by something else. So that would be kind-of risky.

If the function resides in the EXE however, you should be fine. A 32 bit EXE doesn't need relocation information, and most don't include it (MSVC default settings). BTW: ASLR is not an issue here since a) ASLR does only move modules that are tagged as wanting to be moved and b) ASLR could not move a 32 bit windows module without relocation information, even if it wanted to.

Most of the above just makes sure that the function will have the same address on both sides. The only remaining question - at least that I can think of - is: is it safe to call a function via a pointer that we initialized by memcpy-ing over some bytes that we received from the network, *assuming* that the byte-pattern is the same that we would have gotten if we had taken the address of the desired function? That surely is something that the C++ standard doesn't guarantee, but I don't expect any real-world problems from current real-world compilers.

That being said, I would **not** recommend to do that, except for situations where security and robustness really aren't important.